# What is the logic behind this index in Kruskal's minimum spanning tree algorithm?

Tags: python-3.x, minimum-spanning-tree, kruskals-algorithm

I don't understand why we are increasing e += 1 when the parents are not same. And why the while loop stops based on e's value? Why we need that index?

```
def kruskal(self):
    i, e = 0, 0
    ds = dst.disjointSet(self.nodes)
    self.graph = sorted(self.graph, key=lambda graph:graph[2])
    while e < self.v - 1:   # vertices start from zero thats why -1
        s,d,w = self.graph[i]
        i += 1
        x = ds.findParent(s)
        y = ds.findParent(d)
        if x != y:
            e += 1
            self.MST.append([s,d,w])
            ds.union(x, y)
    self.printSolution()
```

ds is disjointSet's object where findParent and union methods are.

Answer (score 0):

Variable `e`, I'd rather call it `edges`, represents a number of edges here. You may ask a question what is the mininum number of edges needed to connect `n` vertices? You can easily prove that's `n - 1`. So we iterate until we have a necessary number of edges to connect all vertices. We're checking parents `x!=y` to be sure there's no cycle.